# Show that $f(1) + \frac{\frac{df}{dx}(1)}{1!}$ +..+ $\frac{\frac{df^n}{dx}(1)}{n!}$ = $2^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

$f(x) = x^n$, where $n \in \mathbb N$.

Show that $$f(1) + \frac{\frac{df}{dx}(1)}{1!} +\cdots+ \frac{\frac{d^nf}{dx^n}(1)}{n!} = 2^n$$

Where $d^nf/dx^n$ is the $n$th derivative.

I know that $y=x^\alpha$ and $y^n=\alpha(\alpha-1)..(\alpha-n+1)x^{\alpha-n}$ but I don't know how to use this to prove the result. Will be thankful if you can help me.

Comment: Correct notation for the $n$th derivative is $$\frac{d^n f}{dx^n}.$$

Comment: One way is to notice that this is nothing but the Taylor series of $x^n$ about the point $a=1$ and then evaluated at $x=2$. A Taylor series of a polynomial is a finite series and always converges.

Comment: $\displaystyle \prod_{\ell=1}^k \frac{n-\ell+1}{\ell} = \binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof without using Taylor expansion :**

For every $1 \leq k \leq n$, you have
$$\frac{d^kf}{dx^k}(x) = n(n-1)...(n-k+1)x^{n-k}$$

so $$\frac{d^kf}{dx^k}(1) = n(n-1)...(n-k+1) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$$

So what you want to compute is

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\left(\frac{d^kf}{dx^k}(1)\right) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{n!}{(n-k)!k!} =\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} = (1+1)^n = 2^n $$

Answer (score 2):

Look at the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x=1$, we have
\begin{align*}
x^{n}=f(1)+\dfrac{f'(1)}{1!}(x-1)+\cdots+\dfrac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!}(x-1)^{n}.
\end{align*}
Now put $x=2$.

Comment: Without using Taylor expansion.

Comment: @VardanDanielyan You may specify in your question that you are looking for a solution that does not use Taylor's formula.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience.